# Unable to direct audio output to USB audio adapter

Tags: 16.04, drivers, usb, sound, alsa

I am following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/UsbAudioDevices) Ubuntu help page. The audio output is not directed by this method.

Configuration details

1) Sound Card details(after attaching [usb audio adapter](http://www.amazon.in/Channel-External-Sound-Audio-Adapter/dp/B01C2F3G10?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=310fbf6d-c4a7-48a3-bd26-35b837082de1))

```
~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7910000 irq 32
 1 [Device         ]: USB-Audio - USB PnP Sound Device
                      C-Media Electronics Inc. USB PnP Sound Device at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, full speed
```

2) USB device with address

```
~$ lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

    Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
```

3) Relevant part of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base` file

```
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
# options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
# options snd-usb-audio index=-2
#USB Magic, part1
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel 
alias snd-card-1 snd-usb-audio
options snd-hda-intel index=0
options snd-usb-audio index=1 vid=0x0d8c pid=0x013c
```

Comment: Plug it and select it in sound settings is usually what needs to be done and nothing else. What's the point of following and old tutorial meant only to troubleshoot?

Comment: @CelticWarrior Post that as an answer!  :-)

Comment: @user589808 because it doesn't work.